# NSClient seems to be ignoring allow_nasty_meta_chars setting

Tags: nagios, nrpe, nsclient++

I am trying to detect an eventlog entry on a server, so am trying to use the `CheckEventLog` command:

```
./check_nrpe -H hostname -c CheckEventLog -a MaxWarn=1 MaxCrit=1 "filter=generated gt -3d AND id=23 AND source='mpio'" truncate=800 unique "syntax=%severity%: %source%: %id%: %message% (%count%)"
```

But, I always get an error back from the client:

```
Exception processing request: Request command contained illegal metachars!
```

I have set the option to allow nasty meta chars, but that doesn't seem to help.

```
[/settings/NRPE/server]
allow arguments = true
allow_nasty_meta_chars = 1
```

If I take out the `source` part of the filter, it works, but of course event id's are not unique in themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nsclient.ini file is not the same as the old nsc.ini so keys and values have changed not just sections.

The key name for "nasty chars" is:

```
[/settings/NRPE/server]
allow nasty characters=true

[/settings/external scripts]
allow nasty characters=true
```

http://docs.nsclient.org/faq/index.html#nasty-metacharacters

Comment: Gah! Perfect. It was the underscores in the key names. I must have found an old example on the internet, and after that not spotted the difference. Thanks!